# Problema na hora de gerar o apk no flutter

Tags: flutter, apk, release

Bom dia!

Tava tudo funcionando normalmente, depois de fazer algumas alterações na comunicação com a api, começou a dar esse erro, já tinha conseguido gerado o apk outras vezes nesse projeto antes dessas alterações.
[image: ERRO]

A única alterações que fiz foi no código do termo lgpd e mudei a versão do android de 29 para 30.

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Você possui um arquivo chamado *key.properties* dentro do seu projeto? Se sim, você pode compartilhá-lo aqui ocultando os campos "storePassword" e "keyPassword"?